# Show/Hide HTML Label without a wordwrap

Tags: html, css, label

Hy,

This are my HTML Code:

```
 <h2>Advertising over Push Notifications</h2>
 <h3>Login</h3>
<label for="infoLabel_CheckUserLoginWeb"></label>
<form id="form_CheckUserLoginWeb" name="form_CheckUserLoginWeb" method="POST" onsubmit="" action="">
    E-Mail: <input type="text" size="30" name="email_CheckUserLoginWeb" id="email_CheckUserLoginWeb" ></br>
    Passwort: <input type="text" size="30" name="passwort_CheckUserLoginWeb" id="passwort_CheckUserLoginWeb" ></br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit_CheckUserLoginWeb" name="submit_CheckUserLoginWeb" />
</form>
```

[image: a image without the label]

[image: a image with the label]

and i want that the text "Benutzername...." will be shown in the red area, i don't want a new wordwrap.

i want this:

[image: the result i want]

Comment: not clear on what you want..

Answer (score 0):

Add additional div in html like this: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fE4WJ/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="error">
    <label for="infoLabel_CheckUserLoginWeb"></label>
</div>
```

then define a rule in css:

**CSS**

```
.error { float:left; height:20px; width: 100%;}
.login {margin:0;}
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not what i mean, sorry... i have edit the post.

Comment: but I cant see any updates in your post. what you want exactly ?

Comment: i have it updated now with an screen, i want it, but i don't know how i can do this!

Comment: it doesn't work because a have a newline between Login and the E-Mail input.

Answer (score 0):

`<h3>` elements have margins by default. Add CSS to remove it:

```
h3{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could insert a id into h3 and add CSS to remove it. Note: if you modify the tag h3 without an id or class, all h3 tags in your code will be modified.

**HTML**

```
<h3 id="login">Login</h3>
```

**CSS**

```
h3#login{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/fE4WJ/2/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<h2>Advertising over Push Notifications</h2>

 <h3 class="login">Login</h3>

<span>Benutzername....</span>

<label for="infoLabel_CheckUserLoginWeb"></label>
<form id="form_CheckUserLoginWeb" name="form_CheckUserLoginWeb" method="POST" onsubmit="" action="">E-Mail:
    <input type="text" size="30" name="email_CheckUserLoginWeb" id="email_CheckUserLoginWeb">
    </br>Passwort:
    <input type="text" size="30" name="passwort_CheckUserLoginWeb" id="passwort_CheckUserLoginWeb">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="submit_CheckUserLoginWeb" name="submit_CheckUserLoginWeb" />
</form>
```

css

```
.login {
    margin: 0;
}
```